# pow value is wrong without a dot

Tags: c, pow

I have this program that makes a geometric mean, I know it can be done with cbrt instead of pow, but my question is the next

```
//medida geometrica de 3 numeros

#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main(){

    double n1, n2, n3, mult, media;

    printf("introduce los 3 numeros espaciados con un espacio cada uno:");
        scanf("%lf %lf %lf", &n1, &n2, &n3);

    mult = n1 * n2 * n3;
    media = pow(mult, 1/3.);


    printf("\nLa media geometrica es de:%lf", media);

}
```

The question is why pow gives me a wrong value if I don't write a dot after the 3 in the pow function
pow(mult, 1/3.)

I mean if i write pow(mult, 1/3) without the dot after the 3 it gives me a wrong value and I don't know why

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `pow`.  The problem is that `1/3` uses integer division, and is therefore `0`.  Whereas `1/3.` is equivalent to `1.0/3.0` which is `.3333333333...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `1/3`, both arguments have integer type so the result is also an integer and you get 0.

When you do `1/3.`, one argument has type `double` so the other is converted to that type and floating point division is done, so you end up with the expected value.

Answer (score 2):

There is a big difference in the result of `1/3` and `1/3.`.

The first uses integer division.  The quotient is `0` and the remainder is `1`, which is thrown out (or truncated), resulting in final value of `0`.

The second uses floating point division which results in the expected value, (approximately) `0.333...`.